# How can I check for a new version of a locally hosted webpage?

Tags: jquery, cordova, compare

I have a program written in HTML/jQuery that resides on a local machine that needs to notify the user of an update when one is released.

I am thinking that the program can compare a local file (local_version.txt or something) to a remote file (remote_version.txt) and if the remote file contains a higher value a notification will display to the user. However if the user is not connected to the internet the function must fail gracefully and not display the notification.

Here is my code so far:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.updateNotification').show().addClass('heightener');
    callback();
},2000)

function callback() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $( '.updateNotification' ).fadeOut();
  }, 10000 );
};
```

My first thought was to just compare 2 DIVs (1 loaded locally, the other remote), however this program is displayed within a webview on the users machine (Xcode/VB/PhoneGap, based on the platform) so I can not use PHP. I am hoping for a jQuery based solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` (or even a cookie) to store the version number and compare them with an AJAX request. Set the version like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('version', '0.8');
```

Then make an AJAX request and compare the version numbers.

This is my example `version.json` file:

```
{"version":0.9}
```

This is my request:

```
$.getJSON('/version.json', function(response){

  var localVersion = +localStorage.getItem('version'),
      remoteVersion = response.version;

  if( localVersion < remoteVersion ) {
    /* Sweet update action! Isn't the awesome thing about the web that we don't have to "update" anything though? */
  }

});
```

The `+` before the `localStorage.getItem('version')` turns it into a number instead of a string so we can safely compare them. `localStorage` stores everything as a string, which I think stinks, but I'm sure people a lot smarter than me have a good reason for it.

Comment: Wow! Such a great detailed answer! I seem to be having some issue with it though. When I place `alert("Update message");` in the if statement it never seems to be true. I checked and my server is sending as type `application/json` (also tried using a local file, with no luck). Do you have any thoughts on how I should go about debugging?

Comment: It's really tough debugging through a person. I'd probably do `console.log( response, localVersion, remoteVersion );` and make sure things are what I believe they are.

Comment: It was an issue that no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header was present in the response from my server (which was an issue as this is a local file). Fixed! Also regarding your comment about web not requiring application updates, I agree, however many of the users of this program are in remote locations without always connected internet access and must access it offline. Having it as installable program made it easiest for these users. In the future I may have another script which will pull updated HTML and replace it on the next load to be more transparent to the user. Thank you again!